# Pandas: Dynamic centering of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need to transform all group columns in a DataFrame except the one column with the output variable.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Branch' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'M1': [1,3,5,8,9,3],
    'M2': [2,4,5,9,2,1],
    'Output': [1,5,5,8,1,3]
})
```

Right now, I am centering all columns, except the output column, manually by listing them explicitly in the group function.

```
def group_center (df):
  df['M1'] = df['M1'] - df['M1'].mean()
  df['M2'] = df['M2'] - df['M2'].mean()
return df

centered = df.groupby('Branch').apply(group_center)
```

Is there is a way to do this in a more dynamic fashion, as the number of variables I am analyzing keep increasing.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a list of the cols of interest and pass this to the groupby which will operate on each of these cols via a lambda and `apply`:

```
In [53]:

cols = ['M1','M2']
df[cols] = df.groupby('Branch')[cols].apply(lambda x: x - x.mean())
df
Out[53]:
  Branch        M1        M2  Output
0      A -2.000000 -1.666667       1
1      A  0.000000  0.333333       5
2      A  2.000000  1.333333       5
3      B  1.333333  5.000000       8
4      B  2.333333 -2.000000       1
5      B -3.666667 -3.000000       3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more vectorized way where you do not need to input your columns anywhere.

```
means = df.groupby('Branch').apply(mean)
df.set_index("Branch", inplace=True)
output = df['Output']
df = df - means
df['Output'] = output

           M1            M2         Output
Branch          
A          -2.000000    -1.666667   1
A           0.000000     0.333333   5
A           2.000000     1.333333   5
B           1.333333     5.000000   8
B           2.333333    -2.000000   1
B          -3.666667    -3.000000   3
```